# What's the reason for the reduction in my reputation?

Tags: discussion

My reputation is reduced without any notification. In fact I can't get to know why I've lost some points!

Even I checked [my reputation list](https://islam.stackexchange.com/users/4666/mohammad-hossein?tab=reputation) but nothing is mentioned there. Why?

**Update:** I know that some fluctuations happened due to the serial voting and users being removed. I mean another reduction other than these reductions.

Comment: Oh, yeah, me too. of course it seems it has happened for many users. but to be frank, as I compared some users, I see that (seemingly) majority of Shia users) are involved.. Actually some other users has missed as well, but I think the reputation of Shia users has decreased more than ... I hope I'm making a mistake and hopefully it is just a misunderstanding!

Comment: @السید____علی unfortunately it did disproportionately affect Shia users. See my answer.

Answer (score 3):

You lost 20 reputation from an answer to a [question that ended up deleted](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/12252/22).

As to why this didn't show up on your account, my guess is it's because you don't have enough reputation to see deleted posts other than your own (even if the answer was your own, the *question* it was under was not, so the whole thread remains inaccessible to you until you have [access to moderator tools](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools).)

Answer (score 1):

See [this answer](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1459/2469). There was some reputation fraud recently which, unfortunately, disproportionately affected Shiite users. You are an innocent bystander, but unfortunately a victim of sockpuppetry.

Comment: I know that some fluctuations happened due to the serial voting and users being removed. I mean another reduction other than these reductions.

Comment: @mohammadhossein the reduction in your rep occurred on January 6 which is the day that the voting ring was broken up

Comment: To my surprise, it happened even after that incident. I've no clues to prove it! How can it be?

Comment: @Daniel, I reckon ur reply could be considered as a fair response, Well done for being honest. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Your reputation history does mention the reason for the loss of reputation, on January 6 you lost 1120 points because four users were deleted.

I can't say for sure why those users were deleted, but likely those were socks used for vote fraud.

Comment: http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/a/1459/2469

Comment: I know that some fluctuations happened due to the serial voting and users being removed. I mean another reduction other than these reductions.